# Combining rows in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

New to pandas - I have a df with columns as 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month' and 'qty'
There are many entries that have identical features (time columns above). I want to combine all rows into one (that have identical hour, day, week, month) and simply sum 'qty' so that every row has a unique set of time features.

My code is below, with the approach being to iterate along the original df and append a row to new df if it is unique with respect to the last, otherwise (if row in new is equal to current row in old) then simply add old df row's 'qty' to the new df row's 'qty'

NOTE: all identical time rows will occur one after another in this set which is why I've taken this approach.

```
    # Group by total slices per hour
    # init merged dataframe
   sicdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Hour', 'Qty', 'Day', 'Week', 'Month'])
   temp = df_sic1.iloc[0]
   sicdf.loc[len(sicdf.index)] = [temp['Hour'], temp['Qty'], temp['Day'], temp['Week'], 
      temp['Month']]
   j = 0
   for i, row in islice(df_sic1.iterrows(), 1, None, 1):
       if (row['Hour'] == temp['Hour'] and row['Day'] == temp['Day'] and row['Week'] == temp['Week'] 
           and row['Month'] == temp['Month']):
           sicdf.at[j, 'Qty'] = temp['Qty'] + row['Qty']
       else:
           temp = df_sic1.iloc[i]
           sicdf.loc[len(sicdf.index)] = [temp['Hour'], temp['Qty'], temp['Day'], temp['Week'], 
               temp['Month']]
           j = j + 1
```

The problem is that it seems to work sometimes, sometimes it will only concatenate a few and continue (i.e. if there are 5 rows that are the same, I'll get two rows rows rather than just one in the new df), etc.
Overall doesn't seem to work. I'm sure there must be an easier way--just haven't seen any posts that help. Thanks!

Comment: Just need some clarity, are you looking to make a pivot table? There's a function for that, if so. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html

Comment: You should try using the GroupBy method - group by the date columns and aggregate the Qty column using sum() method. Read about it here https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/ or there https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html. I don't know much about your data, but you could also consider converting the time-related columns into a single column with a proper datetime format. It will make date-related transformations and aggregations easier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! @nelyanne the GroupBy was exactly what I needed thanks again